# Powershell AD export

Tags: powershell

I am looking to export specific information from my AD environment to upload to Sharepoint online.

Code so far:

```
$ADUSR = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=company,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk" -SearchScope OneLevel -Filter * -Properties * |select name,givenName, sn, department, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, title, manager, streetAddress, l, st, postalCode, telephoneNumber, facsimileTelephoneNumber, otherTelephone, mobile, ipPhone, thumbnailPhoto, employeeNumber, userPrincipalName
$ADUSR | Export-Csv c:\sharepointinfo.csv
```

This works perfectly and should have been straight forward. but the attribute 'thumbnailPhoto' Shows in the csv file as 'System.Byte[]'. 
Run it in PS and it returns and displays as I want. It is exporting that attribute as Decimal how do you export it as Hex? or export the values as shown in AD.

Can you use a Hexidecimal(thumbnailPhoto) with the select part?

Rob

Answer (score 1):

```powershell
$ADUSR = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=company,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk" -SearchScope OneLevel -Filter * -Properties * |select name,givenName, sn, department, physicalDeliveryOfficeName, title, manager, streetAddress, l, st, postalCode, telephoneNumber, facsimileTelephoneNumber, otherTelephone, mobile, ipPhone, @{l="thumbnailPhoto";e={[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.getChars($_.thumbnailPhoto)}}, employeeNumber, userPrincipalName
$ADUSR | Export-Csv c:\sharepointinfo.csv
```

Get ready for your CV to grow **significantly**.